# How to parse/access JSON returned by Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell 4

Tags: json, powershell

I have the following call to an API in a powershell script (Powershell 4.0):

```
$Json = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $RequestURL -UseBasicParsing -Headers $headers -ContentType  'application/json; charset=utf-8' -Method POST -Body $postParams -TimeoutSec 40
```

...and the content of the response (which is a string in JSON format) is written to a file:

```
Set-Content $path -Value $Json.Content
```

An example of a typical response...

```
{
    "MyArray": [{
        "MyField": "A1",
        "MyField2": "A2"
    }, {
        "MyField": "B1",
        "MyField2": "B2"
    }]
}
```

All well and good, but now I have a requirement to parse the returned content as JSON and query some properties from within this Powershell script.

I presume I need to convert my string to 'proper' JSON and then to a powershell object in order to access the properties...so I have tried combinations of ConvertTo-Json and ConvertFrom-Json but can't ever seem to access it in anything other than a string. For example...

```
    $x = $Json.Content | ConvertTo-Json
    Write-Host $x.MyArray[0].MyField

    $y = $x | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Host $y[0].MyArray[0].MyField
```

In both cases above I get an error "Cannot index into a null array" suggesting that MyArray is null.

How do I convert my $Json response object into an object I can drill down into?

Comment: Consider `Invoke-RestMethod`; it automagically takes care of conversion. Aside from that, you seem to actually be after `ConvertFrom-Json ($Json.Content)`; the content *is* JSON, you don't want to convert it *to* JSON. If I copy your response to the clipboard and do `(Get-Clipboard | ConvertFrom-Json).MyArray[0].MyField`, I get the expected result.

Comment: @JeroenMostert -  ConvertFrom-Json ($Json.Content)  results in an error "ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid".

Comment: Hmm, well, piping the input should still work in that case (`$Json.Content | ConvertFrom-Json`). Otherwise something funky is going on with the `Content` object that prevents it from being accessed properly, though I don't know what that could be (encoding mismatch)?

Answer (score 0):

See [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7)

> Converts a JSON-formatted string to a custom object or a hash table.
>
> The ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet converts a JavaScript Object Notation
>   (JSON) formatted string to a custom PSCustomObject object that has a
>   property for each field in the JSON string.

Once you get the response converted to custom object or a hash table, you can access the individual properties

The link includes coding examples

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
    $x = (New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer -Property @{MaxJsonLength=67108864}).DeserializeObject($Json.Content)
    Write-Host $x.MyArray[0].MyField
```

...although not sure why yet.